# PHP 8.2, NumberFormatter::setAttribute only accepts int/float as the 'value' parameter?

Tags: php

While migrating from 7.4 to 8.2, I noticed that I can no longer do the following:

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter(MERCHANT_LOCALE, \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$fmt->setTextAttribute(\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE, "EUR");
$fmt->setAttribute(\NumberFormatter::GROUPING_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL, ""); // Remove thousand separator
$Interval_MinBoundary_Formatted = $fmt->format(\Coupons::AMOUNT_MIN);
$Interval_MaxBoundary_Formatted = $fmt->format(\Coupons::AMOUNT_MAX);
```

setAttribute throws an exception because the 2nd parameter must now be int or float. If that's the case, how do I use setAttribute in conjunction with \NumberFormatter::GROUPING_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL if I want the grouping separator to be anything other than int/float?

What am I missing?

Comment: Oh, I see, $fmt->setSymbol(NumberFormatter::GROUPING_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL, "") is the correct way to go.

Comment: If you think the question is still relevant, you could write an answer to your own question. Else best close it.